Lua conditional evaluation of new language operators
I'm writing a Wireshark dissector in Lua for a custom packet type and Wireshark versions including Lua 5.2 and below (current release versions) have the BitOp library included, whereas upcoming releases will have Lua 5.3 or greater and will use builtin bitwise operations.
My goal is to have this changeover automatically handled by Lua version without having to update the dissector for each version. My current code is:
local bit = nil
if tonumber(string.sub(_VERSION, 5)) < 5.3 then
    bit = require("bit")
end

local version_byte = 0xaf
if bit then
    print("BitOp method")
else
    print((version_byte >> 4) * 10 + (version_byte & 0xf))
end

The issue is that Lua 5.2 (of course) doesn't recognize the bitwise shift and & operators and throws unexpected symbol near '>'. Is there a way to conditionally evaluate something like this?

@AndrewYim It seems that because the error is thrown in compilation it won't even allow reaching the pcall portion. I tested it and the result was no different, still failing when it compiled an "unknown" operator.

Just fyi, Wireshark is still going to support the Lua BitOp library even with Lua 5.3 and 5.4.  To quote the upcoming release notes, "The included Lua version has been updated to 5.4. While most Lua dissectors
should continue to work (the lua_bitop library has been patched to work with
Lua 5.3 and 5.4, in addition to the native Lua support for bit operations
present in those versions), different versions of Lua are not guaranteed to
be compatible.".

This is conditional compilation. Of course, you can.
if bit then
    print("BitOp method")
else
    load[[
        -- arbitrary chunk of code
        print((version_byte >> 4) * 10 + (version_byte & 0xf))
    ]]()
end

However, this will cause problems with access to locals (e.g. local version_byte). So you'll have to rewrite your code accordingly.

Awesome answer, thanks! Accepted.

You could write a couple of compatibility shim modules that define a common interface to the bit operations: one that defines functions that perform bit operations in pre-5.3 Lua, and one that defines functions for 5.3 and later which use the built-in operators under the hood:
-- bit_shim_5_2.lua
-- Defines a common interface to bit operations.
local M = {}

function M.bitop ()
   print("Lua pre-5.3 bit ops")
end

return M

-- bit_shim_5_3.lua
-- Defines a common interface to bit operations.
local M = {}

function M.bitop ()
   print("built-in Lua 5.3 bit ops")
end

return M

-- main.lua
local bit = nil
local version = tonumber(string.sub(_VERSION, 5))
if version < 5.3 then
   bit = require("bit_shim_5_2")
else
   bit = require("bit_shim_5_3")
end

bit.bitop()

Running this program on Lua 5.4.7 yields:
$ lua main.lua
built-in Lua 5.3 bit ops


This is an awesome answer and a good solution. I think for simplicity I'm going with just using load(), but the module solution could definitely be the answer to someone else's needs. For Wireshark it's easier to not have to deal with modules in the Lua dissector folder, but it's a very clean solution for other situations.
